# Error when installing uncompyle6

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
    >>> C:\>Python 3.6.1\Scripts\pip install uncompyle6
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    C:\>Python 3.6.1\Scripts\pip install uncompyle6
                                                  ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

I get this error when I try to install uncompyle6. How can I solve this?

Comment: Did you paste this command from somewhere else? If so, there might be some weird whitespace character at the end.

Comment: That's not Python code you pasted. Pip is a commandline tool.

Comment: whats is the true form??

Comment: See the duplicate. Don't open the Python interpreter, open the cmd.exe console.

Comment: I write it myself

Comment: Thank you martijn I fixed it !!